# how to trigger gitlab pipeline by tags

Tags: tags, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

How to trigger a GitLab CICD pipeline whenever a tag like below gets created? How can I make it in regular expression for all future tags based on the same format?

Tag to trigger the pipeline: `2021.08.31.DEVRELEASE.0001`

Where `DEVRELEASE` is the static keyword, rest of the keywords would change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `rules` and `if` keywords to define your tag's regex. You can use the following snippet and customize the regex to match your desired tag:

```
publish:
  stage: publish
  image: ...
  script:
    - ...
  rules:
    # Runs only when a tag with 'X.Y.Z.DEVRELEASE.A' pattern is created
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.DEVRELEASE\.\d+$/'
```

Comment: Nice to hear that. So, if my answer helped you, please accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: i cannot upvote because of less reputation but accepted your answer. thanks :)